# Simulator or game to teach operating system principles

Tags: operating-systems

I am teaching Operating Systems to Computer Science Majors, generally juniors and seniors. In order to better explain it I want to create or have a simulator or game to illustrate memory management: segmented memory vs. paged memory, demand paging, page replacement algorithms and so on. Have you come across anything along those lines?

Comment: No, but I believe it would be quite an awesome topic for an engineering degree thesis. Maybe for a group thesis

Comment: Computer Science Majors could implement these algorithms themselves to play with them

Comment: Yes they could. Still not a helpful answer.